# Adding two different classes to one function at a different time javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript code and there is one function that I want to add two class to it , but if I add them in the same function line the other class don't work , and when I write each one in the same function but different lines the second class works only , all what I want here is add the first class and add the second class after like 5sec ? I don't know if there is any way to make it work but I hope there is .

this is when the first class only works :

```
function open() {
        en.addClass('op').addClass('bo-ac')
            .removeClass('cl');
    }
```

this is when the second class only works :

```
function open() {
            en.addClass('op')
                .removeClass('cl');
        }  

 function open() {
         $('.bo').addClass('bo-ac')
    }
```

Comment: You have two `open()` function declarations, so the second one overwrites the first one.

Comment: I think it will be useful if you mentioned why you wanna do this

Comment: @VLAZ is there a way that i can add the two classes together and make one work before the other ?

Comment: @S.Alvi the first class is an animated thing so i want the animate works the the second class to execute

Answer (score 1):

@Nothere. I'm not sure, but is this something you are looking for ?

```
function open() {
    en.addClass('op').removeClass('cl');
    setTimeout(function() {
       en.addClass('bo-ac')
    }, 0)
}
```

Comment: Yeah thank you so much , it worked , but can i do any thing to delay the time of the second class execution ?

Comment: You can try adding time in milliseconds instead of 0 as the second argument for setTimeout function. say for 5 seconds delay u can add 5000. But please note, 5 seconds is the minimum delay here and it might take more than that as well to execute.